# How to make and receive calls in MBP via bluetooth?

Tags: macbook-pro, software-recommendation, bluetooth, call

I used to use the HandsFree 2 app. It worked perfectly and it even recorded calls, incredibly useful. But now in Catalina it crashes and it seems is discontinued.

What it did, which would be perfect to have again, is to couple with my smartphone (Android) via Bluetooth. When someone calls, the computer would show a notification and allow me to deny or answer within Mac. Answering the call is like speaking on Skype (earbuds optional).
I could also make a call from the app, which would show my contacts but I could also dial a number and same thing.

I have been scouring for an alternative and have tried a couple (PhoneCall comes to mind), but none of them worked. I'm using an Android phone with modern Bluetooth support and MBP 16" with Catalina 10.15.3.

What options do I have?

Comment: See [this Meta answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Comment: Do you want to talk and listen just on your computer?  I guess I don't know what you want to do.  Lack of knowledge on my part i'm sure.

Comment: @jmh Yes, use the computer like a phone on speaker. What the HandsFree app could do before Catalina

Comment: @fsb Thanks, I think I improved it!

Comment: Is there a setting on your phone that says "allow other devices to make phone call" or something like that?  it so turn that on and see what it says.

Comment: Did you try using Facetime to make a call?  Try that and see if it works. Facetime will do audio only calls as well.

Comment: @jmh I just looked into it, it's only for the Apple cult, so no Android support 